# Do you have data how Alfresco Community behaves with many users connected? (100>)

Tags: load-testing, alfresco, stress-testing

My company is going to use Alfresco as a intranet. I think it's not fastest application and wonder if it can work with few hundred users expected.
Do you have any experience using it with such or larger group?

Comment: Alfresco shouldn't have any problem with just a few hundred users, as it scales happily to hundreds of thousands. Have you tried things like [Tuning your JVM](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fjvm-tuning.html) - having the right settings can make a big difference!

Answer (score 2):

I work for [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com), and can tell you we have customers with hundreds of thousands of users.  We power many public sites (see customer list), among them [Adobe Share](http://www.adobe.com/acom/share/) uses  Alfresco as its backend - it has millions of registered, and thousands of concurrent users.

Comment: Customers mean Alfresco Enterprise, while the OP asked for experiences based on Community. Truth to be told, the codebases are indeed quite close.

Comment: correct - the codebases are almost identical in terms of the core features.  the differences have to do with hardening, testing on more stacks and supporting those stacks.